# Continuing an interrupted `wget` session?

Tags: linux, wget, download

Is it possible to continue an interrupted `wget` session - eg. by parsing the log-file (created with -o or -a ), or after somehow have `wget` store additional information to disk (like it's list over parsed and pending links)?

I know the -N option allows `wget` to pick-up where it left as long as the server support size and date listing, but the site I was downloading had mostly PHP-generated content, so I don't think -N will work.

I don't expect to continue what I started, but if it's at all possible, I'd like to turn-on anything that will help before retrying, in case I get interrupted again.

+++

I also ran into an additional problem...  I got lots of "ERROR 400: Bad Request"...  I assume that means I got a bit *too* eager, so the server blocked me and/or the database got overburdened for a while.  Anyway, would it be possible to recover from that too?  Make `wget` basically continue where it left off (after parsing log or link-list or whatever), but also redo pages where it ran into trouble (eg. after I first edited the list).

Comment: @jimmij I thought that was more for continuing downloading *one* really large file you'd started?   E.g. you're downloading an 4GB ISO-file and gets  cut-off midway... then -c let you continue downloading that file where you left off.  What I need, is a way to continuing harvesting links and downloading from a site I'm trying to mirror.

Comment: export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.if.you.use.one:8080
time -p wget -U " Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;SV1)" --recursive --level=1 --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent --proxy --wait=3 --random-wait --proxy-user=if.you.have.one --proxy-password=if.you.have.one http://target.com

Comment: My answer answers your question, I included wget example above since it sounds like you were trying to get everything on the given website but got bumped off. Many times wget requests can get knocked off because the machine like repetition of your requests gives it away. That is why you need to use the wait and random-wait flags, so wget will appear more like an actual human browsing the site. I am sharing this because information is free, if you have bad intentions, you will pay the price some day.

Answer (score -1):

Wget can be used in different ways, but I assume you are using it to emulate a browser making an http(s) request based on the PHP content.

There is no way to make wget resume a session that was interrupted. The web server wget is interacting with is stateless, so there is nothing there to keep track of exactly what was happening in a session that was interrupted. All you can do is make the request again, which of course isn't going to help you since it will be a new session and can never be the same one as before.

When your wget session was interrupted, that session ceased to exist. The dynamically generated content was dependent on that particular session and was generated only to serve that session. When that session ended, that session's dynamic content effectively ceased to exist. There is no way to somehow go back and resume the now non-existent session or interact with the now non-existent dynamic content which existed only to serve that session.

Remember web servers are stateless. You make a request, and right there on the spot you get the one and only response that will ever be sent to that particular request. More complex things like sessions and dynamic content piggy-back on these stateless requests by passing temporary session IDs and/or tokens to your browser. Then, when your next request comes, the application or PHP script making the dynamic content checks for that session ID/token and responds to your browser in a way that is logically appropriate.

Even if you could somehow reproduce the same session ID and token your browser had before (don't waste your time trying) the odds are 99.99999% that the session ID/token became invalid on the server side within a matter of seconds from the time of your last request anyway.

This is going way past the scope of your question but based on the exact code/script your browser was interacting with on that server, it may be possible to pass fake session ID/tokens, but generally speaking it is not possible to recover an interrupted session. In your case it is not possible at all, since you would have had to try to capture that session ID/token in advance of losing the session in order to try to reproduce it.

Comment: What I'm after isn't necessarily the same server-session (I can see how that'd be difficult), but rather keep going... ie. not downloading what I've already have downloaded, not caring if the page since have changed.  My main problem is 1) identifying which pages has already been retrieved, and 2) which pages/links had yet been downloaded and parsed.  So basically, if I've downloaded the page already, I'll ignore if it's changed since.

Comment: False - you can save the cookies and later reread them. Better answer coming soon